# How to check if the user input exist in an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to check if an user input from text box (for example) exists in an array that I created and imported from other JS files?

And can I link all that code to an HTML button?

In Python to do this I use "in":

```
if a in List: 
    print("That's In")
```

PS: I know that List in Python are a little different with Arrays in JavaScript.

Comment: look at `Array.contains` or `Array.indexOf`

Comment: @Sysix He won't get very far by looking at `Array.contains` ;) [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) exists, though

Comment: [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is the one normally used these days

Comment: so for ur py example, the js equivalent would be `if(list.includes(a)){console.log("That's in")}`

Answer (score 0):

From my platform's JavaScript documentation:

```
//Use:
if (in_array('a', ['a','b',4,'z'])) {console.log('item in array.');}

//Prerequisite functions:
function in_array(s,a)
{
 var r = false;

 if (is_array(a))
 {
  for (var i = 0; i<a.length; i++)
  {
   if (a[i]==s) {r = true;}
  }
 }
 else {console.log('Error: object to in_array ('+a+') is not an array.');
}

 return r;
}

function is_array(a)
{
 return ((a.constructor.toString().indexOf('Array') > 0) ? true : false);
}
```

Comment: Really? Compared to `['a','b',4,'z'].includes('a')` ???

Comment: `const list = ['a','b',4,'z']; if (Array.isArray(list) && list.includes('a')) console.log('list is an array and included "a"'`

Comment: @mplungjan No IE or other older browser support? Really? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: Yes really! isArray: IE9 - polyfill for includes is still shorter than your code `if(!Array.prototype.includes){  Array.prototype.includes = function(search){ return !!~this.indexOf(search); }}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all, i think that i resolved my problem with array.indexOf

 There's my solution below
How can i close the post ?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input style="position:absolute" type="text" id="userInput" /> <br>
  <input style="position:absolute;" type="submit" onclick="name();" /> <br>
  <script type="text/javascript">

function name() {
  var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Mango", "Orange", "Papaya"];
  var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;

 //Check if a value exists in the data1 array
 if(fruits.indexOf(input) !== -1){
   document.write(input, " Value exists!");
   document.write(" Press F5 to reload")
 } else{
   document.write(input, " Value does not exists!");
   document.write(" Press F5 to reload");
}
}
</script>
</form>
</html>
```